# How to pass a parameters under onload function?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body onload="startTime('<%= time %>')">

</body>

<script>
  setTimeout(function startTime(time) {

    alert(time);
  }, 1000) 
</script>
```

I have returned the "time" from the client side by input from another page. Then, the "startTime()" will be called each seconds, in which the "time" parameter will be given to the function.

How can I pass the "time" variable in the `<script>` in every seconds under the onload function.

Comment: Can you use setInterval instead setTimeout?

Comment: You have things backwards. You should call `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` inside the `startTime()` function, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For running it every second, you have to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

You should introduce your `startTime` outside of `setInterval`.

Your `'<%= time %>'` should not be a string too, it should be like this `<body onload="startTime(<%= time %>)">`.

```html
<body onload="startTime(1000)">

</body>

<script>
  function startTime(time) {
    setInterval(function() {
      alert(time);
    }, time)
  }
</script>
```

If `time` is a string you need to parse your time to a number.

```html
<body onload="startTime('1000')">

</body>

<script>
  function startTime(time) {
    setInterval(function() {
      alert(time);
    }, Number(time)) //parse time string to a number
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You're not providing any arguments to be passed as the `time` parameter to the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Though your question isn't much clear, maybe you can use `$('document').ready(function(){});`
inside your script if you use jQuery.
Also if you don't want to use jQuery another approach might be self executing anonymous function like this

```
<script>
(function(time) {
  //this function will we invoked immediately
  console.log(time);
})("Pass params here");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` will run the function after the timer (in your case 1000ms) has run out. If you want it to continuously run every N seconds, you need to use `setInterval` instead.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

You *can* pass arguments to the callback function, by passing a 3rd (or more) argument to the setInterval. But it won't be updated, you need to build your own code around it, so you get the updated value.

What you have in your code right now will not work. You don't call the callback function directly. `setTimeout` starts immediately after the page loads. Your `startTime` function is anonymous, and is essentially this:

```js
  setTimeout((time)  => {
    alert(time);
  }, 1000) 
// alert will be run after 1 second on page load
```

Another recommendation is, to not run code from HTML strings. Keep JavaScript related code inside of JavaScript. You can query HTML Elements inside of JavaScript and depending on if they changed, you can start running the code.